# CSRF session token missing in Apache Superset EC2 instance

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-ec2, csrf, apache-superset

I'm getting "The CSRF session token is missing." when trying to open login in the dashboard page of apache superset. (I'm running the superset docker image on a x86 Amazon EC2 instance)

I tried setting `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False` in the config.py file but got the same error.
I even added the "custom_security_manager.login" to the WTF_CSRF_EXEMPT_LIST in the config file, but no luck.

Note: When running the docker image on local, I am not having any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the latest superset docker image. Was facing the same problem.  Turns out that this is a problem with the latest image. Got to know from [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24579).

The solution is to use the last stable docker image by adding the line below to the `docker-compose-non-dev.yml` file and running it using docker-compose command. 
 `x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:2.1.0`

I was also wondering how to override the configurations when using a docker image. It can be done by making a copy of `./docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config_local.example` into `./docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config_docker.py` (git ignored) and fill in your overrides. [source](https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker#local-overrides)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [TALISMAN_ENABLED = False](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24579#issuecomment-1664311207) into `config.py`. I don't know your version but [3.0.0-py310](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset/tags?page=1&name=3.0.0-py310) works fine. `docker-compose` example:

```
  superset:
    image: apache/superset:3.0.0-py310
    volumes:
      - ./configs:/app/configs
    environment:
      SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH: /app/configs/config.py
    ...
```